# Test only untested modules with Maven

Tags: java, maven, testing

I am working on a java project with multiple modules using maven. Each of these modules has its own set of tests. Sometimes i run all tests on many threads. In the event of a failure in one of the modules, it is sometimes hard to determine which modules are left to be tested since they were being tested all at the same times (Maven shows me a list of all successful/unsuccessfull modules and I sometime have few successfully tested modules at the beginning and the end). In that case, the option "-rf" doesn't solve the problem.

I would like to know if there is a way in maven to resume testing only the untested modules.

Comment: Why not test them all again?

Comment: Because it is time consuming. Some of the modules take 20 or 30 minutes to test. I perform the tests because i am about to checkt in my code and want to be sure I don't "break" the common build.

Comment: If you run the tests from an IDE, such as IntelliJ, you have an option to rerun all failed tests, if this helps you.

Comment: But i also want to run all the untested modules...:(. Also I use eclipse for my development.

Comment: If your tests succeed on a module, you can write that into a file, together with a hash value of your module (i.e. a combined hash value of all your source files). Now, every time the tests are started, they calculate the hash of the files and if they find a success marker for that hash, they just do nothing.